# Windows Firewall - How do I know that I have completely blocked a program?

Tags: windows, firewalls

I have a specific software that I cannot let out to the internet but it is crucial that it has access to the local network.
I can create an inbound and an outbound Block rule for the main application's .exe file(s).

Under their firewall properties, Scope tab, Remote IP window I can add "Internet".  That blocks all internet access but the local network is still accessible.

My big question is:
How on earth do I know that the application only uses the exe file(s) in its Program Files folder and not anything else?  For instance it could use a windows service like svchost.exe to "disguise" itself for communications?  There are dozens of uniform windows service processes that can handle the task I guess.
So how do I know what else I need to create a Block rule for?
I guess I could monitor with Wireshark but I wouldn't be able to tell if it weren't the exe file(s) in the Program Files folder.

Or is it the case that if I block all exe files in the respective Program Files folder the program will be completely restricted to the Firewall rules?

Comment: You want this one program to be blocked but allow everything else on the host to connect to the Internet?

Comment: yes, everything else can be left as default, allowed to access the internet

Comment: Do you know where it might want to reach out to, or do you expect it to be arbitrary in its outbound connections?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a container, not a firewall, to be honest.

Comment: I have no idea where it might reach out to.  Obviously not completely random but can be anything.  So it is a known-unknown case.
I have no experience with containers.

Comment: Run it in a container and you can control the networking, no matter what it wants to do. The concept is "sandboxing" which sounds like the better option if you want the rest of the host to operate without modification.

Comment: ok thanks - which container application do you recommend?  I heard about windows sandbox but it is not available yet on my computer.